# Prove that $H_n(A \sqcup B) \cong H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $A, B$ be topologyical spaces. Then, I want to prove that $H_n(A \sqcup B) \cong H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I know how to prove this from the Mayer-Vietoris theorem, but I'm curious how one might prove it directly from the definition of homology.

Answer (score 4):

The chain complex is itself a direct sum. ;) That is, $C_k(A\sqcup B) = C_k(A)\oplus C_k(B)$ for all $k$, and $\partial=\partial_A\oplus\partial_B$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $H_n(A \sqcup B)$ satisfies the universal coproduct property with inclusions $\iota_X: H_n(X) \to H_n(A \sqcup B) : \sigma \mapsto i_X \circ \sigma $, where $X= A, B$ , and $i_X:X \to A\sqcup B$ are the inclusions, that is, for every pair of homomorfisms $f_X:H_n(X) \to Z $ there exist an unique $\mu : H_n(A\sqcup B) \to Z$ such that $f_X=\mu \circ \iota_X$. For the generators define $\mu$ as $ f_X(\sigma)$ if $\sigma(\Delta) \subset X$